# Binary files not uploading in itunes

Tags: iphone, itunes

My team has developed one app. what we did is, we tried for uploading my app into itunes. We did all correct steps to make it happen. At last step I had to "submit" it to upload it into itunes, but it is showing just "your app is getting uploaded" and uploading bar but not getting uploaded since very long (10 hours).
What could be the reason for this ? I'm stuck.
Please help me out anyone.

Comment: You need to cancel app loader process and go to your iTunesConnect and reject your binary and then again click on "Ready to upload binary". It may happen because of disconnection of internet.

Comment: But there is no any internet connection problem

Comment: And did you mean I should do it again for one more time from start ?

Comment: I m doing it agian, hope gets uploaded this time. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Do I need zip file of .app file or it can be uploaded in both ways ?

Comment: someone help me out ya from this crap

Comment: Sorry for late reply khadar. You need to upload it in zip format only.  Still giving error? If yes then please tell me what kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cancel app loader process and go to your iTunesConnect and reject your binary and then again click on "Ready to upload binary".

It may happen because of disconnection of internet.

Comment: Sorry for late reply khadar. You need to upload it in zip format only. Still giving error? If yes then please tell me what kind of error are you getting?